# how to resolve mismatched types error for linked list implementation in rust

Tags: rust

I have this implementation of a linked list

```
struct ListNode {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}
struct LinkedList {
    head: Option<ListNode>,
    tail: Option<ListNode>,
}

impl LinkedList {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        LinkedList {
            head: None,
            tail: None,
        }
    }
    pub fn add_to_tail(&self, value: i32) {
        let node = self.make_node(value);
        let curr = &self.head;
        while curr.is_some() && curr.unwrap().next.is_some() {
            curr = curr.as_ref().unwrap().next;
        }
    }
```

and I'm getting an error:

```
21 |             curr = &curr.as_ref().unwrap().next;
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `ListNode`, found struct `Box`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&Option<ListNode>`
              found reference `&Option<Box<ListNode>>`
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the code like this to get rid of the type errors:

```rust
    pub fn add_to_tail(&self, value: i32) {
        let node = self.make_node(value);
        let curr = self.head.as_ref();
        while curr.is_some() && curr.unwrap().next.is_some() {
            curr = curr.as_ref().unwrap().next.map(|x| x.as_ref());
        }
    }
```

This way `curr` has the type `Option<&ListNode>` and it is easy to convert other types to it.